# django rest framework - nested serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have those models and serializers:

## models.py

```
class CompanyUserProfile(AbstractUserProfile):
    guid = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_('GUID'), unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('organization'),
        to='my_company.Organization',
        related_name='user_profiles',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('position'),
        to='my_company.Position',
        related_name='user_profiles',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    store_pcs = models.ManyToManyField(
        verbose_name=_('Store PCs'),
        to='my_company.StorePC',
        related_name='user_profiles',
    )
    #
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_('WorkLocation'),
        to='my_company.WorkLocation',
        related_name='user_profiles',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


class StorePC(AbstractOrganizationalUnit):
    store_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        editable=False,
        help_text=_("..."),
        null=True,
        unique=True
    )
    anchor = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        editable=False,
        help_text=_('...'),
    )


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Transcript(TimeStampedModel):
    csod_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        CompanyUserProfile,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='transcripts',
        verbose_name="Company Profile"
    )
    learning_objective = models.ForeignKey(
        LearningObjective,
        verbose_name="Learning objective",
        related_name="transcripts"
    )
    transcript_status = models.ForeignKey(
        TranscriptStatus,
        verbose_name=""
    )
    transcript_status_last_modified = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Transcript Status last modified",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Score,
        null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name="Score",
        related_name="transcripts"
    )
    passed = models.NullBooleanField(
        verbose_name="Has passed"
    )
    requested_on = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Requested on",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    registered_on = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Registered on",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    assigned_on = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Assigned on",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Due date",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    completed_on = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Completed on",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    custom_dashboard = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="",
        default=True
    )
    completion_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name="",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Timestamp"
    )
```

## serializers.py

```
class TranscriptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='get_id', read_only=True)
    value = serializers.IntegerField(source='get_title', read_only=True)
    # segment_id = serializers.CharField(default="N/A", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transcript
        fields = ('id', 'value')

    def get_title(self, obj):
        return obj.learning_objective.title

    def get_id(self, obj):
        return obj.learning_objective.lo_id


class PeopleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name')
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_position')
    los = TranscriptSerializer(source='transcripts', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyUserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'title', 'los')

    def get_full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.get_full_name()

    def get_position(self, obj):
        return obj.position.name



class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    people = PeopleSerializer(source='user_profiles', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StorePC
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'people')
```

however an API query return a result where attribute 'los' is always empty:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 11405,
            "name": "... ",
            "people": [
                {
                    "id": 887,
                    "name": "AAA BBB",
                    "title": "... title 1",
                    "los": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 9263,
                    "name": "XYZ XYZ",
                    "title": "title 3",
                    "los": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
            ...
        }
```

does anybody see any errors that I don't see?

Thank You

Comment: Try adding `transcripts` to `PeopleSerializer` Meta fields instead of `los`

Comment: Did you solve your problem?